# Why do I get 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Im am working on a server-client application. The question is related to a WindowsFroms client side exception which i dont know why ocours.
**Context:** Server stores alarms for traffic lanes. Each lane has a laneID and each lane can "generate" more alarms. Each alarm has a uniqe id (guid). Generally clients request only the guids of the alarms from the server and only those alarms are obtained completely which dont exist at client.
I want to keep track with the server alarms at client side in a DataGridView control efficiently. But sometimes I got **'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'** when trying to remove a row from the DataGridView and I dont know why this happens since I found that element of its rows just before that.
I share only client side codes. First one is the timer tick event handler method. In short, this collect the laneIDs from the user then requests all guids from the server which belong to one of the given lanes. The compare our guids to the new ones and ask for the new alarms. Finally add each element to the control rows.

```
Task task;
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> alarmGuidLaneIdDict;

//Windows.Forms.Timer's Tick method with 300 msec interval
private void AlarmRequestTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //collecting the id-s
        List<string> laneids = new List<string>();
        foreach (LaneView item in layoutPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (item.laneInfo != null)
            {
                laneids.Add(item.laneInfo.Id);
            }
        }
        if (task == null || task.IsCompleted)
        {
            task = new Task(() =>
            {
            //should not do anything if no id present
                if (laneids.Count < 1)
                    return;

                    //getting all existing guids from server for given id-s
                ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> allGuids = Program.webClient.GetAllAlarmGuids(laneids);

                //should select only guids which I dont own
                ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> requiredAlarms = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();    

                //check each of my guids whether it exists in the collection returned by the server
                    foreach (var item in alarmGuidLaneIdDict)
                {
                    if (!allGuids.ContainsKey(item.Key))
                    {

                    //if not exists at serverside then I remove it from my collection
                        alarmGuidLaneIdDict.TryRemove(item.Key, out string tempLaneId);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Item removed from list, because it is not present on the server.");

                        //now lets find the given nonexisting element in my DataGridWiew
                        int rowIdx = 0; int foundIdx = -1; bool found = false;
                        while (rowIdx < myDataGridView.RowCount && !found)
                        {
                            if (found = (myDataGridView.Rows[rowIdx].Cells[6].Value as NetworkChannel.HttpMessages.FullSpeedInfo).guid == item.Key)
                            {
                                foundIdx = rowIdx;
                            }
                            rowIdx++;
                        }
                        if (found)
                        {                                
                            myDataGridView.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {
                                //sometimes argument out of range exception, eg foundIdx = 2 when myDataGridView.Rows.Count = 2
                                myDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(foundIdx);
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                }
                //for each element that exists at serverside but not at clientside
                foreach (var responseAlarm in allGuids)
                {
                    if (!alarmGuidLaneIdDict.ContainsKey(responseAlarm.Key))
                    {
                        requiredAlarms.TryAdd(responseAlarm.Key, responseAlarm.Value);
                        alarmGuidLaneIdDict.TryAdd(responseAlarm.Key, responseAlarm.Value);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Item added: " + responseAlarm.Key);
                    }
                }
               //completely getting only elements which exists at serverside
                RefreshAlarms(Program.webClient.GetAlarms(requiredAlarms));
            });
            task.Start();
        }
    }
```

and the other method:

```
private void RefreshAlarms(List<NetworkChannel.HttpMessages.FullSpeedInfo> alarms)
        {

            if (myDataGridView.InvokeRequired)
            {
                myDataGridView.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { RefreshAlarms(alarms); }));
            }
            else
            {                
                foreach (NetworkChannel.HttpMessages.FullSpeedInfo alarm in alarms)
                {
                    //do nothing yet
                    OnSpeedingEvent(alarm);
                }

                if (alarms == null)
                    return;
                //adding each new alarm to the DataGridView, the last cell is the object itself
                for (int i = 0; i < alarms.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (alarms[i].alarmInfo == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(alarms[i].guid))
                        continue;

                    myDataGridView.Rows.Add("Play", alarms[i].guid, alarms[i].timeStamp.ToString(), ((int)alarms[i].speed).ToString() + " km/h", alarms[i].laneInfo.location, alarms[i].GetPriority(), alarms[i]);

                    int rowCount = myDataGridView.Rows.Count;
                    if (alarms[i].GetPriority() == "Significant")
                        myDataGridView.Rows[rowCount - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                    else if (alarms[i].GetPriority() == "Important")
                        myDataGridView.Rows[rowCount - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                    else if (alarms[i].GetPriority() == "Warning")
                        myDataGridView.Rows[rowCount - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have already tried to clear the the whole DataGridView in each Tick and just add every alarm at once after that, but then it flickers and resets the scrollbars making it useless.
Any advice which helps me solve the exception or other concepts which makes the DataGridView up to date are appreciated.
Other info: Alarm objects contain image data. Number of objects stored in the server is vary, can grow +5 new alarms/min to +100 alarms/minutes, its almost random. Client can remove any selected item from the DataGridView.

Comment: It might help if you let us know what line causes the error.

Comment: @StoneGiant It's commented in the code.

Comment: @LarsTech *face palm* Thanks.

Comment: You've got a timer that ticks every 300ms. On each tick you're creating a new task that calls out to a webservice and then attempts to make changes to a DataGridView. I'm going to speculate that you're kicking off multiple tasks as they aren't completing before the next tick. The first task is probably removing the item while the 2nd task/subsequent tasks are also attempting to remove the items. Try increasing the tick interval to 1 second and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: @HandbagCrab ...or don't run the code if it hasn't been completed yet from the previous run.

Comment: @LarsTech yes that too. Increasing the tick interval is a trivial task which is why I suggested it as a quick test.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of multiple threads operating on these controls, between use of `Task.Start` and then `BeginInvoke` when removing items, which also uses a separate thread.

As a result it's very difficult to tell if what's happening in the code is going to happen in the expected order. You might find an item you want to remove at position three, but before you remove it another item gets removed, and now the one you were about to remove is at position two and there is nothing at position three, which would give you the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

When these sort of threading issues occur, it's very common for them to occur inconsistently. That might explain why the error happens "sometimes."

One way to fix this is to ensure that you're not doing any of these three things at the same time:

- Adding rows
- Looping through rows and figuring out which ones to delete
- Deleting rows

You could likely solve this using a `lock` to ensure that only one of these things is going on at a time.

Also, instead of deleting rows as you find rows to delete, build a list of rows, and when done, delete them all at once, taking care to always delete them in descending order. Otherwise if you try to delete row 10 followed by row 11, after deleting row 10 the row that was at 11 is now at 10. Now if you delete 11 you're deleting the one that was at 12. Or there is no 11 and you get the exception again.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the Tick interval did not help me. But,
I found the exact reason of the exception and a solution. 
When I was calling

```
myDataGridView.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {                                
                                myDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(foundIdx);
                            }));
```

multiple times, then the order and the time of their execution were undeterministic, because these are async calls. After I replaced the myDataGridView.BeginInvoke(...) to myDataGridView.Invoke(...) no more exception occured.

Thank you for pointing to the right direction :)